# uninitialized constant ActionController::RedirectBackError Did you mean? ActionController::RenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

Trying to implement `redirect_to :back` method
but I'm getting this error:

`uninitialized constant ActionController::RedirectBackError Did you mean? ActionController::RenderError`

my *posts_controller.rb*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActionController::RedirectBackError, with: :redirect_to_default

  def publish
    post = Post.find params[:id]
    post.publish!
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_default
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

my rails version is: `6.0.3.3`
and ruby version: `ruby 2.7.1p83`

Comment: ActionController::RedirectBackError does not exist in Rails 6.  Check out the updated way introduced in Rails 5 https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/29/rails-5-improves-redirect_to_back-with-redirect-back.html

Answer (score 3):

dbugger is right you might want to try this instead : `redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)`